Reproducing XZ Utils backdoor on Kali Linux
I want to learn about the XZ Utils backdoor by following the xzbot exploit demo and setting up the environment. I know version 5.6.1 of xz-utils should have the backdoor, but I can't manage to install this compromised package.
Starting with a clean Kali Linux 2024.4 environment, it has liblzma 5.6.3 and sshd does not seem to depend on libsystemd and liblzma. Apparently neither stock or portable OpenSSH comes with systemd support. I'm confused by all the guides expecting sshd to be already linked to liblzma, while it just isn't for me.
└─$ dpkg -l | grep liblzma5
ii  liblzma5:amd64                                 5.6.3-1+b1                               amd64        XZ-format compression library

└─$ ldconfig -p | grep liblzma
        liblzma.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5

└─$ sshd -V
OpenSSH_9.9p1 Debian-3, OpenSSL 3.3.2 3 Sep 2024

└─$ ldd $(which sshd)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fc3de0b8000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fc3ddfde000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007fc3dda00000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc3dd80a000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fc3dd768000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc3de0ba000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc3ddfbe000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fc3dd6a7000)

When downgrading to the liblzma 5.6.1 package and checking ldd again, nothing appears to have changed.
└─$ wget https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20240328T025657Z/pool/main/x/xz-utils/liblzma5_5.6.1-1_amd64.deb             
2024-12-24 00:45:29 (4.72 MB/s) - ‘liblzma5_5.6.1-1_amd64.deb’ saved [252188/252188]

└─$ sudo dpkg -i ./liblzma5_5.6.1-1_amd64.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading liblzma5:amd64 from 5.6.3-1+b1 to 5.6.1-1
(Reading database ... 425071 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ./liblzma5_5.6.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblzma5:amd64 (5.6.1-1) over (5.6.3-1+b1) ...
Setting up liblzma5:amd64 (5.6.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.40-3) ...

└─$ dpkg -l | grep liblzma5
ii  liblzma5:amd64                                 5.6.1-1                                  amd64        XZ-format compression library
                                                                                          
└─$ sudo systemctl restart ssh

└─$ ldd $(which sshd)                                                                                               
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007f705e59b000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f705e4c1000)
        libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007f705de00000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f705dc0a000)
        libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007f705e41f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f705e59d000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f705e3ff000)
        libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007f705db49000)

Then I tried to build OpenSSH 9.7p1 since that is before the backdoor became public, if that would maybe help. This required a restart before sshd -V showed 9.7p1
wget https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-9.7p1.tar.gz
tar -xvf openssh-9.7p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-9.7p1
sudo apt install libssl-dev
./configure
make
sudo make install


But both libsystemd and liblzma were still not linked to sshd.

At this point I'm clueless how to even install or build the vulnerable xz-utils package. I had similar problems when trying the same steps with Ubuntu 24.04

please post text, not pictures of text ... you have done it correctly already

According to this
openssh does not directly use liblzma. 
However debian and several other distributions 
patch openssh to support systemd notification, 
and libsystemd does depend on lzma.

And from Debian's OpenSSH changelog
openssh (1:9.7p1-4) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Rework systemd readiness notification and socket activation patches to
    not link against libsystemd (the former via an upstream patch).
  * Force -fzero-call-used-regs=used not to be used on ppc64el (it's
    unsupported, but configure fails to detect this).

 -- Colin Watson <cjwatson@debian.org>  Wed, 03 Apr 2024 12:06:08 +0100

They refactored the code to support systemd notifications without linking against this after a certain version.
You can reproduce the vulnerable setup using the debian:12 container. Personally, I love reproducing setups with containers as they are much more reliable in reproducing a workload (no more "but it works on my machine").
And the learning curve isn't too bad:
Isolated process. Isolation happens at the kernel level. Different abstracts called namespaces are created for said process. Said process is assigned to them.
Namespaces such as Network Namespace, Mount Namespace and PID Namespace, to name the most important ones.
Subprocesses inherit the same namespaces (so, if we start off with bash in a container, anything we run will be in the same namespaces)
Anyway:
docker run --publish 127.0.0.1:22:22 --rm --interactive --tty --entrypoint=bash \
  docker.io/library/debian:12  

apt update
apt install -y wget "openssh-server=1:9.2*" bsdmainutils  # Last one is for `hexdump`
wget https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20240328T025657Z/pool/main/x/xz-utils/liblzma5_5.6.1-1_amd64.deb
apt-get install --allow-downgrades --yes ./liblzma5_5.6.1-1_amd64.deb
path="$(ldd $(which sshd) | grep liblzma | grep -o '/[^ ]*')"
  
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' "$path" | grep -q f30f1efa554889f54c89ce5389fb81e7000000804883ec28488954241848894c2410 \
  && echo "Found!"


We explicitly ask for a vulnerable version of openssh-server

Last line's output:
root@7f1a3034bee9:~# hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' "$path" | grep -q f30f1efa554889f54c89ce5389fb81e7000000804883ec28488954241848894c2410 && echo "Found!"
Found!

Container's sshd version and ldd output.
root@7f1a3034bee9:~# sshd -V
OpenSSH_9.2, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024

root@7f1a3034bee9:~# ldd $(which sshd)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff38da2000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fce9e57a000)
    libwrap.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 (0x00007fce9e56e000)
    libaudit.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x00007fce9e53d000)
    libpam.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x00007fce9e52b000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fce9e45b000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fce9e42b000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007fce9e3d8000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007fce9e2fe000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007fce9e2f8000)
    libcrypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 (0x00007fce9de72000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fce9de53000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fce9dc70000)
    libnsl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.2 (0x00007fce9dc55000)
    libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x00007fce9dc4d000)
    libcap.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 (0x00007fce9dc41000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fce9dafa000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fce9dabb000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007fce9d9ff000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fce9d9d9000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fce9e6f3000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fce9d93f000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007fce9d912000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007fce9d904000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007fce9d8fb000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fce9d8ea000)
    libtirpc.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtirpc.so.3 (0x00007fce9d8bc000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fce9d894000)
root@7f1a3034bee9:~# 

Let's just break down the docker run arguments:

--publish 127.0.0.1:22:22 - On the host's 127.0.0.1:22 publish the container's :22 port. In other words, route traffic (using iptables, under the hood) from 127.0.0.1:22 to the container's 22.
--rm - Destroy the container once its entry process (basically, its pid 1 in its own pid namespace) exits. In this case bash. In other words, when we're done with the container.
--interactive - Attach to the container's stdin so we can tell bash what to do. The legit version of nc -l -p <port> -e /bin/bash.
--tty - With the --interactive, attaches the container to our tty in case anything we run needs a terminal.
--entrypoint=bash - Override the container image's entrypoint with our own selection, bash. Probably the default but force of habit.

At this point, you can start, in the container, sshd (with its default listening port of 22) and, on your host, whatever traffic goes to localhost:22 (so, it isn't open on your LAN and onwards), will be routed to the container. You can see this routing defined in iptables (by docker).
Sorry about misleading you before.

It does not seem to be a valid option.
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-systemd

@Ketho Sorry. Fixing my post momentarily.
